# Mac App Store - link to App Review Page

Tags: macos, app-store

In the iOS versions of our software we prompt users to submit reviews using the well know "viewContentsUserReviews" URL.

We'd like to do the same thing in the Mac OSX versions of the apps. Is there a similar URL that can be used for the Mac App Store?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24):

I have part of an answer. To link directly into the Mac App Store you need to use the MAS protocol which is "macappstore:". This can be found by looking in the info.plist for the MAS app.

Some experimentation has found that using part of the URL from the link to an app will work in the MAS app. So if I copy the link to my app from the MAS app it looks like this:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ringer-ringtone-maker/id402437824?mt=12

Of course using this does not open directly in the MAS app. But you can remove the store country designator and the name of the app and add the MAS protocol and you get this:

macappstore://itunes.apple.com/app/id402437824?mt=12

Which opens the main page for an app directly in the MAS app. I have not yet found a way to link directly to the rating page. Since the rating section in the MAS is just a part of the main page that is revealed it is possible that there is no link directly to it. I would love it if that were not true.

Perhaps someone else can find this last bit. In the meantime I plan on using the link to the main page as a fallback until the rating page URL can be found.

Comment: Is there any way to find out the id before the app is public in the store?

Comment: @hendrik Yes, you can find it in iTunes Connect in the General App Information section as the 'Apple ID' value

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you @Jon Steinmetz

Answer (score 24):

**macOS 10.14 Mojave and up**

This works with the new Mac App Store on Mojave

```
macappstore://apps.apple.com/app/idxxxxxxxxx?action=write-review
```

If you also want to support iOS as well, use this general link:

```
https://apps.apple.com/app/idxxxxxxxxx?action=write-review
```

Replace xxxxxxxxx with your App ID. (can be found on App Store Connect)

Brings you here:
[image]

*Swift code example for Apple Pages:*

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/requesting_app_store_reviews

```
guard let writeReviewURL = URL(string: "macappstore://apps.apple.com/app/id409201541?action=write-review")
            else { fatalError("Expected a valid URL") }
        
NSWorkspace.shared.open(writeReviewURL)
```

*SwiftUI example for Apple Pages:*

```
if let appStoreID {
      Link("Rate this app", destination: URL(string: "https://apps.apple.com/app/id\(appStoreID)?action=write-review")!)
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you find this one, Daniel? :)

Comment: There is a sample code by Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/requesting_app_store_reviews).

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 15):

As the link provided by Dave doesn’t work anymore as of OS X Yosemite, I investigated a bit and found this updated version of his link:
`macappstore://userpub.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZUserPublishing.woa/wa/addUserReview?id=YOUR_APP_ID&displayable-kind=30`.

As Dave already mentioned, this links to the App’s page and opens the "Write a Review" section. But the App Store doesn’t scroll down to the section, so on small screens the user thinks he’s only been taken to the normal App’s page. So I dug a bit deep and also found those links (same base URL), that don’t return a fully functional (App Store) page, but instead return content that is normally called via AJAX requests on an App’s page inside the app store:

- `/writeUserReview?id=YOUR_APP_ID&displayable-kind=30` – links directly to the "Write a Review" section content
- `/userRateContent?id=YOUR_APP_ID&displayable-kind=30` – links directly to the "Rate this App" 5-stars rating call
- `/saveUserReview?displayable-kind=30` - links to the page, that saves user-ratings

Note: On the last two links I removed some parameters, because otherwise they could be used to rate and review any app (the user has bought) without user interaction!

I don’t know if this is really helpful to somebody, but I wanted to write it down here, as somebody else might be interested in this.

Comment: Thank you @max, that was really helpful for me.

Comment: It's a shame these don't have the correct CSS styling, so they look really ugly and hacky.

Answer (score 4):

To link directly to the MAS store's "Write a Review" section, link to:

macappstore://userpub.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZUserPublishing.woa/wa/addUserReview?id=%d&type=Purple+Software

and replace %d with your app id.

Comment: This URI fails (in 10.9.2) with:

    "Your request produced an error.
    [newNullResponse]"

Comment: I just tested again on 10.9.2 and it still works correctly. You can't enter that URL into Chrome as it doesn't know how to handle macappstore:// URL's but entering it into Safari, or executing `open macappstore://userpub.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZUserPublishing.woa/wa/addUserReview?id=734258109&type=Purple+Software` in terminal works as expected.

Comment: My bad, I substituted that %d with full ID as used everywhere else, including the "id" prefix. It has to be just the numeric part here.

Answer (score 0):

In iTunes Connect, under Manage Applications, click the app you want to provide a link to. There should be a link called "View In App Store". Wouldn't this work?

Comment: No - that just takes you to the product page. I am looking for a way to get directly to the review page for an app in the MAS, as can be done for the iOS App Store